# How to pass a YML config file in Docker Image during run

Tags: docker

I have built a docker image. It has a YML config file which is a large configuration something like this

```
contrydata:
  continent: europe
  country: luxembourg
  county: luxembourg
  town: luxembourg
...
```

I am using this configuration file during the run of docker. I want to use this as a default configuration. If any user wants to change the configuration how does this config file passes to the docker image during the run.

I have seen a few docker run command like this which uses an external config file

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 80:80 dockerhub/mydockerimage:v3 --config config.yml
```

Where users can configure this file and can pass it from an external source.

In a nutshell, if users pass a config file then the default config file will be replaced with the provided `config.yml` file otherwise the default `config.yml` file will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually done, as far as I can tell, is to map the config file to a specific location in the container. Nginx does this and has a volume mapping on the `docker run` command like this `-v /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`. The Nginx container then always looks for the config file in the same location - `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

I've never seen it passed as a parameter as you show. Those parameters will be passed to the program defined as the entrypoint in the container. That program doesn't have access to the host file system, so unless the config file has been mapped to the container using a volume, the program won't have access to the file.

Edit:
Just for the fun of it, I tried making this Dockerfile that builds a small C program that prints out any arguments passed to it. I also created a shell script that passes any arguments on to `pgm`. This is pretty much how Tileserver does it.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo '#include <stdio.h> \n\
int main(int argc, char **argv) { \n\
  for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) { \n\
    printf("%s\\n", argv[i]); \n\
  } \n\
}' > pgm.c
RUN gcc -o pgm pgm.c
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n\
./pgm "$@"' > docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 775 docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

If you build and run it using the commands

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test --config config.file
```

it prints out

```
./pgm
--config
config.file
```

If you wanted to do it like Tileserver, the C program would then need to open `config.file` and use the contents. But of course it would only be able to get at it, if the file is mapped using a volume.

Comment: here you can find the exact command in this docker. I am using this image since long. `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl:v3 --config config.json –verbose`. See this `--config config.json` part. I always change my configuration here. I got the idea from this docker image.

Comment: That works because they take the config file from `/data/config.json` and the current directory on the host is mapped to `/data` using the `-v $(pwd):/data` volume mapping. If you want to pass in a file from the host, you have to do it with a volume mapping of some sort. Once you've done the mapping, you can tell the container where to find it (like tileserver-gl does) or you can have a convention for where the config file is (like nginx) does.

Comment: yes, I want to know the exact process. I tried but couldn't do it.

Comment: Basically, the docker image runs a script that passes any options on to the tileserver server program. That understands the `--config` parameter and uses the file specified. So it's not a docker mechanism. You can look at the dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh here to see how they do it. https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl